# Smart contract that accepts custom token

Tags: contract-development, tokens, testnets, rinkeby

I've successfully created my own custom token on the Rinkeby testnet. Upon creation of the token I sent all the new coins to my wallet. I can send the new token to other wallets just fine and it shows up.

However I'm having difficulty writing a smart contract to accept the new token. I've sent the token from my wallet to the contracts address and it's been confirmed. However within the contract I can't see that it has received the token.

Answer (score 1):

You must read [this](https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/ethereum-smart-service-payment-with-tokens-60894a79f75c)

The process is more complicated but it still does its job so I think it's worth it

Answer (score 0):

Currently the [ERC-20 Token Standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md) do not specify how to notify a contract when tokens are send to them.

There's a [proposal ERC-223](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223) with a new specification that stablishes how to notify when funds are sent to a contract.

Workarounds using ERC-20, involve a two step procedure:

1. `token.approve(contractAddress, amount, { from: userAddress })` User approves the contract to retrieve a given amount of tokens
2. `contract.purchase(token, amount)` User calls contract to indicate it has been approved (function name varies with contract)

   2.1 `token.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount)` Contract transfer token from the user to the contract in the specified amount